# No redirection when drag & drop file

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I have a rectangle where I should be able to drop some files. The thing is, when I drop them, the browser redirects to the file. I know it's normal, but since I'm trying to drop the file in order to upload it...

I found out that e.preventDefault() should be what I'm searching for, but it's not actually working.

Here's my code :

```
<div id="dropHere">
    <p>Drop your files here...</p>
  </div>

  <script>
    dropHere.addEventListener("drop", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
  </script>
```

I have some code I didn't put here (javascript and css).
Can you help me figure out why e.preventDefault() is not working ? (It should, right ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer, even though it doesn't make it work

I finally figured out what was wrong : in order to drop a file into the browser, I need to do e.preventDefault() on both "drop" and "dragover"

So this works :

```
dropHere.addEventListener("drop", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
dropHere.addEventListener("dragover", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

But thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the method

```
dropHere.addEventListener("drop", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

correctly load into your browser, you need to do something like this:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  dropHere.addEventListener("drop", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
};
</script>
```

This binds onload to an anonymous function, that when invoked, will run your desired function, with whatever parameters you give it. 
Of course, you can run more than one function from inside the anonymous function.